# Arithmetic schemes with the same zeta function

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, arithmetic-geometry

Suppose $X$ and $Y$ are $n$-dimensional regular separated schemes of finite type over $\mathbb{Z}$ such that *number* of $\mathbb{F}$-points of $X$ and $Y$ are equal for all finite fields $\mathbb{F}$.

What is the geometric connection between $X$ and $Y$ (perhaps after adding homeomorphic conditions at the archimedean places as well)? Are there invariants of $X$ and $Y$ beyond their Betti numbers that are equal or isomorphic? For example, are their $l$-adic cohomologies strongly related if not isomorphic?

I suppose I am essentially asking: how much does the zeta function tell us about the geometry of an arithmetic scheme?

Also, depending upon the answer to the question above, can we construct moduli spaces of all such schemes with a given zeta function, i.e., would they be expected to vary in families?

Comment: maybe you should assume separatedness. Otherwise it seems that the affine line with double origin and the projective line have equal number of points. Also connectedness (affine line+point and projective line have equal number of points).

Comment: @crispr: good point! edited per your suggestion.

Comment: They certainly don't have isomorphic cohomology, for example for any fiber bundle $X \to B$ with fiber $F$, $X$ has the same zeta function as $B \times F$, but the cohomology has no reason to be the same. I am not sure what one can expect but I'm not an expert

Comment: @NicolasHemelsoet what exactly do you mean by fibre bundle? It has to be Zariski-locally trivial for the zeta functions to agree; for example Severi–Brauer schemes do not have this property. Do you have an example of the type of phenomenon you're talking about?

Comment: @R.vanDobbendeBruyn : I mean indeed fiber bundle in the Zariski topology. For example $\Bbb P^1 \times \Bbb P^1$ and any non-trivial Hirzebruch surface are $\Bbb P^1$-bundle over $\Bbb P^1$ but they don't have the same cohomology ring. I think for smooth fiber bundles in the Zariski topology, the cohomology always agree additively using the Grothendieck ring of varieties.

Comment: @NicolasHemelsoet the motive (or zeta function) can only see the cohomology group, not the ring structure. I think the natural and interesting question is about the cohomology groups. (Even here there are of course obvious counterexamples, like $\mathbf G_m \amalg \{\operatorname{pt}\}$ and $\mathbf A^1$, so some further assumptions are needed.)

Comment: I would recommend looking at Serre's book "Lectures on $N_X(p)$". In it he proves various things closely related to your question.